# MIPS $ra address is not word-aligned?

Tags: exception, assembly, stack, runtime, mips

I'm working on a project for a university exam which consists in encrypting a message with simple algorithms, and I just don't understand why this part of code doesn't work.

I call the *encryptE* procedure with a `beq` instruction in the main, then I jump to the *searchEquals* label with an `jal` instruction, and inside this I need to call other procedures (*intTOascii* and *stackPop*).... for this reason I have to save the address in `$ra` of the first `jal` call on the stack, but when I run the code with mars it gives me the error:

Runtime exception at 0x004002c0: store address not aligned on word boundary 0x7fffeff7

I think I understand what kind of error it is, but I have not understood why the address in `$ra` is not word-aligned

The only thing is that in some procedures I used the stack to save some characters and pull them out in reverse order through the `lb` and `sb` instructions .... but those portions of code should come later (in *intTOascii* for example), and in any case it shouldn't give problems since all the characters that I push inside then I pop out them

I'll leave the part of the code in question below, the two lines that give me error are almost at the bottom. Thanks in advance for the help :)

```
# Algoritmo di criptazione E
encryptE:   
    move $s6, $zero                     # inizializzamo in $s6 l'offset per il bufferTmp
    move $s7, $zero                     # inizializzamo in $s7 l'offset per il bufferMsg


    copyLoop:                           
        lb $s0, bufferMsg($s6)          # Carica in $s0 l'elemento del bufferMsg in posizione $s6

        beqz $s0, endCopy               # Se l'elemento in $s0 è 0 (ovvero il carattere ASCII [NULL]) si esce dal ciclo

        sb $s0, bufferTmp($s6)          # Copiamo l'elemento $s0 nel bufferTmp

        addi $s6, $s6, 1                # incrementiamo $s6 per andare a leggere il carattere successivo nella prossima iterazione
        j copyLoop                      # saltiamo allo statement copyLoop per iterare sul buffer

    endCopy:    
        move $s6, $zero                 # riinizializzamo in $s6 l'offset per il bufferMsg


    nextE:                                      
        lb $s0, bufferTmp($s6)          # Carica in $s0 l'elemento del bufferTmp in posizione $s6

        beqz $s0, endE                  # Se l'elemento in $s0 è 0 (ovvero il carattere ASCII [NULL]) si esce dal ciclo

        jal checkDuplicate              # salto jal a checkDuplicate che controlla che il carattere in $s0 non sia gia presente nel bufferMsg

        sb $s0, bufferMsg($s7)          # nel caso $s0 non sia già presente nel bufferMsg lo inseriamo
        addi $s7, $s7, 1                # incrementiamo di un byte l'offset $s7

        move $a0, $s6                   # creiamo una copia dell'offset $s6 e la passiamo come argomento a searchEquals attraverso il registro $a0

        jal searchEquals                # salto jal a searchEquals che scandisce il buffer per trovare tutte le posizioni del carattere in esame

    adef:

    skip:                               # label di ritorno da checkDuplicate nel caso il carattere sia già presente nel buffer
        addi $s6, $s6, 1                # incrementiamo $s6 per andare a leggere il carattere successivo nella prossima iterazione
        j nextE                         # saltiamo allo statement nextE per iterare sul buffer

    endE:       
        j return                        # torniamo allo statement return della procedura chiamante  


    checkDuplicate:     
        move $t7, $zero                 # inizializzamo un offset per scandire bufferMsg dall'inizio

        startCheck:
            beq $s7, $t7, endCheck      # se $t7 = $s7 (offset principlae di bufferMsg) si esce dal ciclo

            lb $t0, bufferMsg($t7)      # Carica in $t0 l'elemento del bufferMsg in posizione $t7

            beq $s0, $t0, skip          # se $t0 = $s0 (carattere in esame), $s0 è gia nel buffer e si salta a skip
            addi $t7, $t7, 1            # incrementiamo di un byte l'offset $t7
            j startCheck                # saltiamo allo statement startCheck per iterare sul buffer

        endCheck:       
            jr $ra                      # saltiamo all'istruzione succesiava alla chiamata


    searchEquals:   
        lb $t0, bufferTmp($a0)          # Carica in $t0 l'elemento del bufferMsg in posizione $a0

        beqz $t0, endSearch             # Se l'elemento in $t0 è 0 (ovvero il carattere ASCII [NULL]) si esce dal ciclo

        beq $s0, $t0, regPosition       # se $t0 = $s0 (carattere in esame) si si salta a regPosition

        addi $a0, $a0, 1                # incrementiamo di un byte l'offset $a0
        j searchEquals                  # saltiamo allo statement searchEquals per iterare sul buffer

        regPosition:    
            addi $t1, $zero, 45         # salviamo in t1 la costante 45 (codice ASCII del carattere '-')
            sb $t1, bufferMsg($s7)      # inseriamo l'elemento $t1 nel bufferMsg    
            addi $s7, $s7, 1            # incrementiamo di un byte l'offset $s7

            ################################################
            # These are the two lines that give me the error
            ################################################

            addi $sp, $sp, -4           
            sw $ra, 0($sp)              # Runtime exception at 0x004002c0: store address not aligned on word boundary 0x7fffeff7

            jal intTOascii              

            jal stackPop

            addi $a0, $a0, 1
            j searchEquals

    endSearch:  
        addi $t0, $zero, 32
        sb $t0, bufferMsg($s7)
        addi $s7, $s7, 1

        lw $ra,3($sp)
        addi $sp,$sp,8
        jr $ra
```

Comment: _" I have not understood why the address in $ra is not word-aligned"_ That's not what the error is saying. The store address is `0($sp)`, so you have messed up `$sp` somehow.

Comment: `lw $ra,3($sp)` looks really weird. Why 3? And why are you adding 8 to `$sp` after the load when you only subtracted 4 before the store?

Comment: ups don't consider ```lw $ ra, 3 ($ sp)``` .... I was trying to do random things to see if it worked ... I had seen that subtracting 8 from the stack for some strange reason it didn't give me error, but then in the intTOascii function used to insert 3 empty characters in the buffer, so here is that 3, in any case it didn't work and I forgot to fix it

Comment: so, if i understand, it is the stack pointer that is not aligned .... but the fact is that before that statement I don't use the stack, at least for now. The final program includes a cycle where the various algorithms are applied in a certain order, set by me, so it may happen that you access the stack even before that instruction, and I am afraid of this :P, but for now it is the first instruction in which $sp appears in the code

Comment: Set breakpoints at every instruction that uses `$sp`, and re-run your program.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense to only modify `$sp` at the beginning and the end of your program. This way, you avoid the mistake of modifying it too much in a loop and not resetting it properly. Maybe try saving all s-Regs you need and `$ra` at the beginning and restore them shortly before you jump back. Could we have the code for `intTOascii` and `stackPop`, too, please? Especially the latter sounds like it might mess things up.